# Draw axis guid line via Python in Blender

Tags: python, objects, 3d-view, interface, 3d-manipulator

I write a little addon that reset location by a single axis (X, Y or Z).
I want to add the possibility to view axis guide line in 3d viewport when you select one. Like you have in transformations(move, rotate, scale) when you choose the axis.

I didn't find command to draw specific global axes.
Can you help me with that?!

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking to do some thing similar.